# C source files not allowed when not using cgo or SWIG: sqlite3-binding.c

Tags: go, docker, alpine-linux, gogs

I'm trying to compile gogs with the sqlite tag for alpine, I need to create a statically linked bin because otherwise I get a file not found if I try to run the ADD'ed bin from within an alpine container.

Here's what I'm doing:

1. Cloning the develop branch from the gogs repo
   `git clone --depth=1 -b develop https://github.com/gogits/gogs`
2. cd to run the build
   `cd gogs`
3. Trying a go get with CGO_ENABLED
   `CGO_ENABLED=0 go get -a -ldflags '-s' -tags "sqlite" -u ./...`

And I get:

```
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
package github.com/gogits/gogs: exit status 1
package github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3: C source files not allowed when not using cgo or SWIG: sqlite3-binding.c
```

Comment: gogs requires CGO for the SQLite package. You can't build it without CGO.

Comment: Just use the Debian image. It's not that huge (~150MB) and it contains libc (which allows you to use CGO).